# How to compare a String with Hashmap key?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I wana compare a String with the Key of a Hashmap.

So every time i run this code it uotputs : Not found

I'm new at Java and its surely a little thing but i need help.

Here my code

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(!txtSearchHere.getText().isEmpty() && txtSearchHere.getText().length() > 1)
            {
                String value = txtSearchHere.getText();
                txtSearchHere.setText("");

                for(Integer key : plzHashMap.keySet())
                {
                    if(key.toString() == value)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Matched key = " + value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use `key.toString().equals(value)` as `==` will compare if it is the same object (reference) whereas `.equals()` compares the values.

Comment: Try key.toString().equals(value)

Comment: I think your logic is wrong. Are you sure that you want the USER to enter a KEY? Based on your "txtSearch" variable, I assume you are not intended to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all String-comparisons in Java you should use `.equals()` instead of `==`.

So change:

```
if(key.toString() == value)
```

to:

```
if(key.toString().equals(value))
```

The reason for this is that `==` is used for checking if the instances are the exact same (reference), while `.equals` checks for the same value.

[See this SO question (among a lot of others) for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
String.valueOf(key).equals(value)
```

And never compare String with ==, use .equals().

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, compare strings using `.equals()`, not `==`.

Secondly, it outputs `Not found` lots of times because that statement is inside the loop. You can move it outside the loop:

```
            boolean found = false;
            for(Integer key : plzHashMap.keySet())
            {
                if(key.toString().equals(value))
                {
                    System.out.println("Matched key = " + value);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
```

However, it would be a lot easier just to convert `value` to an `Integer`:

```
Integer intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

and then just call `get` and `hasKey` - no looping required:

```
if (plzHashMap.hasKey(intValue)) {
  System.out.println("Matched key = " + plzHashMap.get(intValue));
} else {
  System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

Of course, you'd need to handle the case that `value` can't be parsed to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator checks for reference **identity**. You should use the `equals` methods to check for **equality**:

```
if(key.toString().equals(value))
```

But regardless, you're using an O(n) iteration on a hashmap which was designed to provide `O(1)` key lookup - why not use it?

```
boolean found = false;
try {
    Integer integerValue = Integer.valueOf(value);
    if (plzHashMap.containsKey(integerValue)) {
        System.out.println("Matched key = " + value)
        found = true;
    }    
} catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
    // value is not even a number
}

if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```